# Angular firebase and observable error handling

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, observable

I’m struggling to understand how to add some error detection to angular firebase when using the code below. When new users login to my website they don’t have any permissions on the database and an error is thrown in the console.

I’m just trying to get it so that if this error is thrown auth.isApproved returns false, at the moment it doesn’t return. I’ve tried adding a .catch to the .switchMap and that didn’t work.

Error in console:

> Uncaught Error: permission_denied at /authorization/users/VAST9WnazFUc6u9PQ5x74bOPIsJ2: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.

Consuming component:

```
this.auth.isApproved().subscribe(approved => {
  console.log (approved);
```

AuthService (auth):

```
isApproved(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.user$
    .switchMap(user => this.DataService.getSharesDBUser(user.uid).valueChanges())
    .map(appUser => appUser.isApproved)
  }
```

DataService (DataService)

```
getSharesDBUser(userUID : string ): AngularFireObject<firebaseDBUser> {
    return this.db.object('/authorization/users/' + userUID);
  }
```

Interface

```
export interface firebaseDBUser {
  isAdmin                  : boolean;
  isApproved               : boolean;
  name                     : string;
}
```

Comment: The error shows you don't have permission to read the data `/authorization/users/VAST9WnazFUc6u9PQ5x74bOPIsJ2` from the database. It seems that you're attaching the listener after the user is authenticated (otherwise the UID would be undefined). Can you show your security rules?

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks. The user has no read rights on the DB, that's what I'm trying to catch in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess would be to add a `catch` operator on the `switchMap` inner observable, but you say that it doesn't work :/

```
isApproved(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.user$.switchMap(user =>
        this.DataService.getSharesDBUser(user.uid).valueChanges()
            .map(appUser => appUser.isApproved)
            .catch(() => Observable.of(false))
    )
}
```

If the `catch` operator cannot catch this error, it should be because the error isn't triggered inside the `valueChanges` observable chain, maybe it's right before, in the `this.db.object(...)` function call. In this case, a simple `try-catch` around the call should do the trick.

Comment: Hi Noémi, thanks. That look similar to what I tried, it throws this error. ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError:  
_this.DataService.getSharesDBUser(...).valueChanges(...).map(...).catch is not a function
TypeError: _this.DataService.getSharesDBUser(...).valueChanges(...).map(...).catch is not a function

Comment: To use `catch` operator you need to patch Observable with `import "rxjs/add/operator/catch"` (or something like that)

Comment: Thanks Noémi, assumed it was okay as my IDE \ Build didn't show an error. It's working great now, many thanks.